# Is there shortcut to affect several buttons appearing on form?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void clearBoard()
{
    button1.Text = null;
    button2.Text = null;
    button3.Text = null;
    button4.Text = null;
    button5.Text = null;
    button6.Text = null;
    button7.Text = null;
    button8.Text = null;
    button9.Text = null;
}
```

I have 9 buttons. (`button1` - `button9`). I want them all to clear the text.
There is more efficient way to do that instead of clear each one normally?

BTW, I know i can create array of buttons but here, all the buttons created on from window manually. so maybe here it's impossible.

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? WPF?

Comment: I prefer to make my own list of buttons.  Searching form for controls is slow.  Try this : List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>() { button1, button2 };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only enhancement I can come up with is to put your buttons in a list or array. If you create your buttons manually, one way would be to declare a member variable in your Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

    //...
}
```

And add your buttons to that list when you create them:

```
private void CreateNextButton()
{
    Button button = new Button();
    // initialize button
    Controls.Add(button);

    // add button to your list
    buttons.Add(button);
}
```

Then change your `clearBoard` to:

```
private void clearBoard()
{
    foreach(Button button in buttons) button.Text = string.Empty; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to clear text for all buttons in Form, use this :

```
foreach (Control b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        b.Text = string.Empty;
```

But if you want clear text for only 9 Buttons, there are various methods, among them the both below :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    var button = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b.Name == "button" + i).FirstOrDefault();
    if (button != null) button.Text = string.Empty; 
}
```

Or you can use also this :

```
List<Button> listButtons = new List<Button>() { button1, button2, button3,
    button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9 };
foreach (var item in listButtons)
    item.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: What if he has other buttons as well on his form?

Comment: OP never stated that he wants to clear _all_ buttons on the `Form`, but only these specific 9. If there are no more buttons, I'd prefer your answer.

Comment: Thanks, if i will add other button it cause a problem. isn't any other method like this?: int i = 0, For (......) { button{0}.text = null; i++;}????

Comment: you want just the empty 9 buttons or all added buttons ?

Comment: only 9 buttons to be cleared. others must keep showing text

Comment: You can see the second way in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simpler form is to loop over the page's controls, and set the text property for buttons only.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in Page.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Button)
        {
            ((Button)control).Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you should loop over the parent control where the buttons are layered. If they are inside a div, loop over that div (say it's id is myDiv) - like:

```
foreach(Control control in myDiv.Controls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your controls and check if it's a `Button`, if so, set the `Text` property to `null`

```
foreach (var button in this.Controls)
{
    if (button is Button)
    {
        ((Button)button).Text = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the Window itself, you could do

```
private void ClearButton()
{
    foreach (var control in this.Controls)
    {
        Button btn = control as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            btn.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```